# JavaScriptSerializer Deserialize Json Array of a Different Kind

Tags: c#, arrays, json, deserialization

I see that this sort of question has been asked before. However, all the great examples posted here are a little different from mine. I can't seem to find an example with a Json array that looks like this one and I have tried at least 2 dozen examples and every type of deserialize code that will compile, but no matter what I try, I can't get this to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my Json that comes back.

```
{"Value": [
    {
        "BirthSexId": 1,
        "BloodTypeVerificationPending": false,
        "CenterPatientId": "80671472",
        "DateOfBirth": "1970-02-16T00:00:00",
        "EthnicityRace": [
            1048576
        ],
        "FirstName": "Candidate",
        "HasParentRegistration": false,
        "LastName": "323820260",
        "ListingCenterCode": "HHHH",
        "ListingCenterType": "TX1",
        "ListingDateUsedByMatchUtc": "2011-01-21T19:17:26.04Z",
        "MedicalUrgencyStatusId": 4099,
        "RegistrationAddDateUtc": "2011-01-21T19:17:26.667Z",
        "RegistrationId": 681292,
        "RegistrationInactiveReasonId": 7,
        "RegistrationOrganCode": "KI",
        "Removed": false,
        "SocialSecurityNumber": "323820260",
        "VerifiedBloodTypeCode": "A"
    },
    {
        "BirthSexId": 2,
        "BloodTypeVerificationPending": false,
        "CenterPatientId": "72240245",
        "DateOfBirth": "1974-04-17T00:00:00",
        "EthnicityRace": [
            33554432
        ],
        "FirstName": "Candidate",
        "HasParentRegistration": false,
        "LastName": "322823847",
        "ListingCenterCode": "HHHH",
        "ListingCenterType": "TX1",
        "ListingDateUsedByMatchUtc": "2019-07-01T21:13:28.61Z",
        "MedicalUrgencyStatusId": 4010,
        "RegistrationAddDateUtc": "2019-07-01T21:13:28.693Z",
        "RegistrationId": 1203041,
        "RegistrationOrganCode": "KI",
        "Removed": false,
        "SocialSecurityNumber": "322823847",
        "VerifiedBloodTypeCode": "A"
    }
],
"ValidationResults": [] }
```

Here is my C# Class

```
public class UnosRegistration
{
    public Int32 BirthSexId { get; set; }
    public Boolean BloodTypeVerificationPending { get; set; }
    public String CenterPatientId { get; set; }
    public String DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public Int32[] EthnicityRace { get; set; }
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public Boolean HasParentRegistration { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; set; }
    public String ListingCenterCode { get; set; }
    public String ListingCenterType { get; set; }
    public String ListingDateUsedByMatchUtc { get; set; }
    public Int32 MedicalUrgencyStatusId { get; set; }
    public String RegistrationAddDateUtc { get; set; }
    public Int32 RegistrationId { get; set; }
    public Int32 RegistrationInactiveReasonId { get; set; }
    public String RegistrationOrganCode { get; set; }
    public Boolean Removed { get; set; }
    public String SocialSecurityNumber { get; set; }
    public String VerifiedBloodTypeCode { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my C# code snippet

```
response = (HttpWebResponse)myWebRequest.GetResponse();

dynamic responseString;

responseString = new StreamReader( response.GetResponseStream() ).ReadToEnd();

List<UnosRegistration> jsonResult = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize( responseString, typeof( List<UnosRegistration> ) );

var RegID = jsonResult.FirstOrDefault().RegistrationId;
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that your JSON has a `Value` key which contains an array of `UnosRegistration`. Telling your code to deserialize a `List` of `UnosRegistration` will not work since the deserializer will look for an array at the top level of your JSON and it is not there.

To solve this problem you will need a wrapper class, this class will contains a `List<UnosRegistration>` property called `Value` like this:

```
public class Wrapper
{
    public List<UnosRegistration> Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then you deserialize like this

```
Wrapper jsonResult = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Wrapper>(responseString);
```

Comment: Oh Thank You So Very Much!